# OpenCV vs Core Image

Tags: ios, opencv, core-image

I have worked with Core Image, creating filters and stuff. Also I'm aware that Core Image has feature detection capability.

I have also worked a bit with OpenCV, but not on a mobile device. Used it for very basic purposes.

Core Image is a lot simpler than OpenCV in terms of coding, but I still see a lot of activity going on in the OpenCV community w.r.t iOS. I wanted to know some applications where OpenCV can be preferred over Core Image.

Answer (score 5):

The main goal for Core image is to perform operations on images. As you mentioned in your question, you can create filters and modify images.

OpenCV however, has a far broader scope. As the name implies, it provides tools for all kinds of computer vision applications. It can be used for facial recognition, object recognition, 3D scanning, but also applying filters to images.

I have no idea what you mean by "require it to be used". As far as i'm concerned, every application requires to be used. There would be no point in writing an application if you are not using it.

Comment: As you just mentioned, facial recognition in iOS requires OpenCV to be used. I was looking for those kind of applications where OpenCV is "required to be used". Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Adithya you are welcome to write your own code for facial recognition on iOS. OpenCV isn't required, it just makes programming easier for computer vision applications.

Comment: @Alexey Without OpenCV, what would it take to implement something like  that in iOS? Any particular framework or just calculations?

Comment: You can read a research paper on the subject and prototype an algorithm of interest from scratch. But it is time consuming and requires some knowledge of machine learning /image processing. OpenCV library is popular because it is free and implements a broad scope of computer vision algorithms.

Comment: OpenCV does make such a thing much easier. Building a facial recognition from scratch would be rebuilding many of the things that openCV has some kind of support for.

Comment: Core Image DOES provide some basic facial recognition (iOS >=5.0) - if you don't have time to use openCV and just need that (1 rectangle for face, 1 point for each eye, and 1 point for mouth), it's way quicker : http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-easy-face-detection-with-core-image-in-ios-5